# IBM Watson Unity SDK IAM Authentication

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-watson

In the IBM Watson Unity SDK, using the `IamAuthenticator` to initialize a Watson Service with your API Key generates a token that is then used by the service to make IBM Watson API requests. Do these tokens expire?

I know a new token must be requested every hour using the IBM Watson Node SDK in combination with a browser app, but does the `IamAuthenticator` not take care of refreshing the tokens for you in the Unity SDK? If not, how would I go about refreshing the token every hour, do I just create a new `Authenticator` object every time and thus a new service object? Or is there a utility method for this?

The documentation for this SDK is not very good, would appreciate if someone pointed me in the right direction for this.

Comment: the same way you do for getting one in the first place

Answer (score 1):

please check out the IAM section in [Readme](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk#iam). You can use IAM API key if you want SDK to manage the lifecycle of the token, please see the following [docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/watson?topic=watson-iam) if you wanna learn more about IAM.